# Data not showing in pyqt UI

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt, window

I created a button in a main window that when clicked will bring up a search window with a tree widget containing rows of data from a MySql database. If I were to open the search window through the .py file on its own it displays the data, but when I open it through the button I programmed, no data is shown. This is the code for the program that runs the main window and creates a button function to open the search window:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from MainMenu import Ui_MainWindow
from StudentSearch import Ui_Student_search
import DB_manager_students

class MainWindow(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.window2 = None

    def handleButton(self):
        if self.window2 is None:
            self.window2 = Student_search()
            self.window2.show()

class Student_search(Ui_Student_search):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What am I doing wrong? And why is it that it will display the data if I open it by itself, but not when I open it like so?

Edit:

From Student_search.py

```
class Ui_Student_search(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, database, tableName):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.dbu = DB_manager_students.DatabaseUtility(database, tableName)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.UpdateTree()

(...)

def UpdateTree(self):
    col = self.dbu.GetColumns()
    table = self.dbu.GetTable()

    for c in range(len(col)):
        self.StudentTreeWidget.headerItem().setText(c, col[c][0])

    self.StudentTreeWidget.clear()

    for item in range(len(table)):
        QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.StudentTreeWidget)
        for value in range(len(table[item])):
            self.StudentTreeWidget.topLevelItem(item).setText(value, str(table[item][value]))
```

Edit:

[image: Student search]

Comment: does the window show up?

Comment: How is Student_Search being updated?  I don't see any code that would pull info from a mysql database?  What is Ui_Student_search?  Are you doing the update in the `__init__` method?  Because you're not calling `Ui_Student_search.__init__` from `Student_search.__init__`

Comment: Ui_Student_search is the class created in the in the StudentSearch.py file. I have created an UpdateTree() function that will populate the table in Student_search.py, which I've added to the question.

Comment: @DDVlad. So did you take the advice given above? Or try using `super(Student_search, self).__init__(parent)`, so you don't have to worry about calling the right base-class `__init__`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say I'm not calling Ui_Student_search.__init__ from Student_search.__init__ . Also, I tried using super(Student_search, self).__init__(parent) but it says I am missing one required positional argument "tablename". tableName is a variable I defined at the end of my StudentSearch code as the table in MySql that contains the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is your base widget class

```
class Ui_Student_search(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, database, tableName):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.dbu = DB_manager_students.DatabaseUtility(database, tableName)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.UpdateTree()
```

When you instantiate `Ui_Student_search()`, the `Ui_Student_search.__init__()` method runs, which creates a database utility, creates the GUI, and runs `UpdateTree()`.

Now, you create a new class -- `Student_search` -- that inherits from the `Ui_Student_search` class

```
class Student_search(Ui_Student_search):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

But when this class is instantiated and `Student_search.__init__()` is run, it only does half of the things that `Ui_Student_search.__init__()` was doing.  It doesn't create the database manager or update the tree.

What you should be doing is calling the parent class `__init__` method so that `Ui_Student_search.__init__()` can run and do all those things.  Also realize that you'll need to pass `database` and `tablename` arguments to the `Ui_Student_search.__init__` method.

```
class Student_search(Ui_Student_search):

    def __init__(self, database, tablename, parent=None):
        Ui_Student_search.__init__(self, parent, database, tablename)
```

Python has an even simpler syntax to call methods on the base parent class.

```
class Student_search(Ui_Student_search):

    def __init__(self, database, tablename, parent=None):
        super(Student_search, self).__init__(parent, database, tablename)
```

This also means that you'll need to update your `MainWindow` to feed the necessary contructor arguments to `Student_search`

```
def handleButton(self):
    if self.window2 is None:
        database = '???'
        tablename = 'xxx'
        self.window2 = Student_search(database, tablename, parent=self)
        self.window2.show()
```

Comment: I have tried using both methods, however, when I click on the button, it displays the error TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tableName' at super(Student_search, self).__init__(parent) or Ui_Student_search.__init__(self, parent). Why does it give me this error? Can it not find tableName in Ui_StudentSearch? I put the code for where  and what tableName is in the question. I don't understand why it can't use or find tableName.

Comment: One thing that got missed in the comments, is that the signatures also need to be changed.  So something like `(self, database, tableName, parent=None)` is required on both classes. Also note that in the OPs example, the relevant parameters are not being passed in when creating the instance of `Student_search`.

Comment: When saying that they are required on both classes, do you mean both the class Student_search in the main file and Ui_Student_search in the other .py file that I am calling? Also, what do you mean when you say the parameters are not being passed in? And how would I be able to change that?

Comment: Thank you. For super(Student_search, self).__init__(parent, database, tablename) it states that __init__() takes 3 positional arguments, but 4 were given, so I had to remove parent, and now it seems to work.

Comment: One last thing, if you could help, and I'm sorry if I am wasting your time or causing inconvenience, but when the student search window comes up, there is this little slider bar in the top left corner for some reason that is not there in the original window. I showed the picture in the question (covered the names, for data protection reasons). Is this to do with the code in the Main Window, or is it a problem from the source StudentSearch.py file?

Comment: @DDVlad. It's a widget in the search dialog that you have not put in a layout.